# Ho do you put multiple arrays into Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I am trying to train this tensor flow image recognition. I am feeding it two separate file folders full of the images, however it will not work and I think it's an array error. I have ran it before with one folder full of images and it worked fine its when I switched to two folders and designed that architecture that I started to get the errors. I have a feeling it might be something so do with the fact they I doubled the labels but im not sure. Looking for all advice but remember Im very new to both neural networks/deep learning and python but appreciate the help non the less.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from random import shuffle
from tqdm import tqdm

CCW_DIR = 'C:\\Users\\cward\\Desktop\\images\\gz2\\ccw'
CW_DIR = 'C:\\Users\\cward\\Desktop\\images\\gz2\\cw'
IMG_SIZE = 50
LR = 1e-3

MODEL_NAME = 'dogsvscats-{}-{}.model'.format(LR, '2conv-basic')

def label_img(imgCW):
    #word_label = img.split('.')[-3]
    return[1,0]
    #word_label == 'cw': return[0,1]
def label_img(imgCCW):
    return[0,1]

def create_train_data():
    training_data = []
    for imgCCW in tqdm(os.listdir(CCW_DIR)):
        labelCCW = label_img(imgCCW)
        path = os.path.join(CCW_DIR, imgCCW)
        img = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE), (IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
        training_data.append([np.array(imgCCW), np.array(labelCCW)])
    for imgCW in tqdm(os.listdir(CW_DIR)):
        labelCW = label_img(imgCW)
        path = os.path.join(CW_DIR, imgCW)
        img = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE), (IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
        training_data.append([np.array(imgCW), np.array(labelCW)])
    shuffle(training_data)
    np.save('train_data.npy', training_data)
    return training_data

train_data = create_train_data()
```

And this is the error I am getting after the program runs through both folders of images:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-40719067ea74> in <module>()
----> 1 train_data = create_train_data()

<ipython-input-42-fa8590694b2d> in create_train_data()
     12         training_data.append([np.array(imgCW), np.array(labelCW)])
     13     shuffle(training_data)
---> 14     np.save('train_data.npy', training_data)
     15     return training_data

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in save(file, arr, allow_pickle, fix_imports)
    507 
    508     try:
--> 509         arr = np.asanyarray(arr)
    510         format.write_array(fid, arr, allow_pickle=allow_pickle,
    511                            pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py in asanyarray(a, dtype, order)
    542 
    543     """
--> 544     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)
    545 
    546 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

Sorry for the bad python im am VERY new to this language. Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error in your question because `training_data` is a list of numpy arrays, and [`numpy.save()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) can only save a numpy array. I'd suggest you *stack* those arrays with [`numpy.stack()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) right before saving, but a further issue is that even the elements of `training_data` are lists.

A usual way of going about this would be to have one numpy array to hold the training data, and another for the labels. (Note that numpy can also shuffle with [`numpy.random.shuffle`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html), but be careful to keep the images and labels in sync.) Then save them separately, or together with [`numpy.savez`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html#numpy.savez).

An easy fix would be to use Python's [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) to save (and later load) the data, that can handle all kinds of objects, not just arrays, but that's much slower, which might or might not be a factor for you based on the size of your data.

A separate comment: defining the `label_img` function twice will result in the second one being the one to run. Much like

```
a = 5
a = 256
```

will result in `a`'s value being 256.